# Redirecting to home page if scroll to div not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I dont know how well i can explain my problem so i have made two html files and try to explain my problem using those files.

I am using scroll to div element using jquery(the code i have taken from web) in my home page. so when a user clicks a link it will scroll down to that particular element in homepage. The problem is when the user move out of home page and to other webpages then those link becomes dead and will not work.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Scroll Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="main-wrap">

            <h1>This is scroll demo</h1>

                <div id="con1">
                    <h3>Container 1</h3>
                    <img src="./img/img1.jpg" alt="image 1" />
                </div>
                <div id="con2">
                    <h3>Container 2</h3>
                    <img src="./img/img2.jpg" alt="image 2" />
                </div>
                <div id="con3">
                    <h3>Container 3</h3>
                    <img src="./img/img3.jpg" alt="image 3" />
                </div>
                <div id="con4">
                    <h3>Container 4</h3>
                    <img src="./img/img4.jpeg" alt="image 4" />
                </div>
                <div id="con5">
                    <h3>Container 5</h3>
                    <img src="./img/img5.jpeg" alt="image 5" />
                </div>
                <div id="con6">
                    <h3>Container 6</h3>
                    <img src="./img/img6.jpg" alt="image 6" />
                </div>
                <div id="con7">
                    <h3>Container 7</h3>
                    <img src="./img/img7.jpg" alt="image 7" />
                </div>
                <div id="con8">
                    <h3>Container 8</h3>
                    <img src="./img/img8.jpg" alt="image 8" />
                </div>
                <div id="con9">
                    <h3>Container 9</h3>
                    <img src="./img/img9.jpg" alt="image 9" />
                </div>
            <div class="nav">

                <ul id="navlist">
                                              <li><a href="#con1">Container 1</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con2">Container 2</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con3">Container 3</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con4">Container 4</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con5">Container 5</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con6">Container 6</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con7">Container 7</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con8">Container 8</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con9">Container 9</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="lol.html">Container 10</a></li>
                                    </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
<style>.main-wrap { width: 960px; border: 1px solid #CCC; margin: 0 auto }
    img { max-width: 100%; }

.nav { background: #DDD; position: fixed; right: 10px; top: 10px; }
    #navlist, #navlist li { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    #navlist li { margin: 20px }
    #navlist li a { padding: 20px }
</style>
<script>
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

    var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }

});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**lol.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Scroll Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="main-wrap">

            <h1>container 10</h1>

                <div>
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                    <p>


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
                </div>                

            <div class="nav">

                <ul id="navlist">
                                              <li><a href="#con1">Container 1</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con2">Container 2</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con3">Container 3</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con4">Container 4</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con5">Container 5</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con6">Container 6</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con7">Container 7</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con8">Container 8</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="#con9">Container 9</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="lol.html">Container 10</a></li>
                                    </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
<style>.main-wrap { width: 960px; border: 1px solid #CCC; margin: 0 auto }
    img { max-width: 100%; }

.nav { background: #DDD; position: fixed; right: 10px; top: 10px; }
    #navlist, #navlist li { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    #navlist li { margin: 20px }
    #navlist li a { padding: 20px }
</style>
<script>
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

    var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }

});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

in this sample webpage it has 10 menus (container1-10). in this 10 menu 9 of them (container 1-9) will only work in index.html. container 10 menu links to another page lol.html.

The problem is when user is in **lol.html** if user click any menu from container 1-9 nothing happens. I want to redirect users to home page to that element when clicked container 1-9.

Hope i didn't confused anyone

Comment: is it possible for u to add code in lol.html

Comment: What about adding page URL before anchor in `href` like this : `/homePage.html#con1`. Sure it will cause clicks in homePage to reload, but could do the trick

Comment: @EdenSource if page reloades then the smooth scrolling gets affected. i used especially scroll to div to prevent any kind of page reloads. scrolling is much more visually attractive

Comment: First you can keep only anchors on home's navlist, and create a function on ready that trigger a click on `A` which has `href` containing the anchor retrieved from the URL (am I clear ?)

Answer (score 2):

First, edit your `A` tag in pages that are not the homePage for :

```
<li><a href="/homePage.html/#con1">Container 1</a></li>
```

And then, you can use something like this to detect a `click` from another page in your homePage:

```
//Used for the demo, just get the window's location
var simulatedURL = "www.domaine.org/#case4";

var getAnchor = simulatedURL.split("#");

$('a[href="#' + getAnchor[1] + '"]').trigger("click");
```

Please see the [quick Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5epwmdvh/)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work for you..

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
 var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );
 if(target.length==0)
   window.location.href='index.html'+$(this).attr('href');
 else
 {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you navigate to lol.html from your home page you can use history.back to get back the previous page.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
history.back();
});
```

Comment: not working? what if the user lands on lol.html first (organic searches)instead of home page. will this code will work on that time?

Comment: single page application keep your content inside the index.html and show ,hide the contents accordingly

Comment: thanks for explaining but i cant use that in my case